# How do I change \" back to " in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

I'm a beginner to Node.js and MySQL so bear with me. The code below is in my routes for my localhost server and the database when saved at first is fine, but when I try to retrieve it and push it back into my database by storing the old one in a new array, it changes the "" to \"\". What I want is for it to be still "".

I've tried looking around the web for ways to change the formatted string quotes from \"\" back to "" but to no avail and I also tried formatting the score  from string back to a number but I realized that even if I did that, it would still end up being a string when stored in the database and when I retrieve it, it would be the same.

```
    let { score } = req.body;
    let { date } = req.body;
    score = Number(score);

    var score_date = [score, date];

    wMissing.findOne({
        raw : true
    }).then((missing) => {
        var sessionID = missing.testSessionID;

        registerPatient.findOne({
            where: {
                nric : sessionID
            },
            raw : true
        }).then((patient) => {
            var height = patient.height;
            height = height / 100
            var weight = patient.weight;
            var bmiVar = (weight / (height * height)).toFixed(2);


            // *This is where my problem starts*

            if (missing.wMissingScore == null){
                var newArray = score_date;
            } else {
                var newArray = [missing.wMissingScore];
                newArray.push(score_date);
            }

            newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray);

            wMissing.update({
                bmi: bmiVar,
                wMissingScore: newArray,
                name: patient.fullname,
                nric: sessionID,
                datePlayed: date
            }, {
                where: { 
                    nric: sessionID
                }
            }).then(() => {
                res.redirect('workoutDiets');
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The expected output is supposed to be `[["2","24/7/2019"],["3","24/7/2019"]]`

But instead I'm getting `["[\"2\",\"24/7/2019\"]",["3","24/7/2019"]]`

I'm still unaware of any method to change back the \"\" to "" instead. can anyone please help me to improve on my code?

Comment: its an escape char since your result is under double quotes, if you have a chance of changing it to single quote, i mean in javascript

Comment: @James sorry, I still don't get it

Comment: Get rid of `newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray);`

Comment: @charlietfl but if I get rid of it, they will tell me that my array is unable to be stored in the database.

name: 'SequelizeValidationError',
  errors:
   [ ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'wMissingScore cannot be an array or an object',
       type: 'string violation',
       path: 'wMissingScore',
       value: [Array],
       origin: 'CORE',
       instance: [wMissing],
       validatorKey: 'not_a_string',
       validatorName: null,
       validatorArgs: [] } ] }

Comment: Ok...then when you retrieve that field you will need to use JSON.parse() on it to turn it back to array from json

Comment: @charlietfl ah yes! that did the trick. Thank you so much! I completely forgot about the  JSON.parse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl mentioned about JSON.parse() and it worked! I just changed my else statement to

```
var newArray = [JSON.parse(missing.wMissingScore)];
```

and it managed to save the score back to what it originally was.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what's happening is that the first element of the array is being stored as a string, if you watch carefully, the second element is written correctly as an array of strings.

The problem is the first element, you're having a special case.

If i understand correctly ´´´missing.wMissingScore´´´ is a pure string

What you can do is:

´´´

```
if (missing.wMissingScore == null){
                var newArray = score_date;
            } else {
                var formatedMissingScore= missing.wMissingScore.replace("\"", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
                var newArray = [formatedMissingScore];
                newArray.push(score_date);
            }
```

´´´

That way you're formatting your first element string so its not text anymore and should match what you are trying to get.

Comment: Thank you as well for your answer, but I have solved it already with the help of one of the other members here. I can't accept my own answer until 2 days later though :-/ so that's going to be a pain